# How do I get in python the path/name of the calling module inside another module called by import

Tags: python-2.7, import, ironpython

The problem looks like this: Imagine a package/module `abc.py` that provides basic functionality to a framework (e.g. `open`, `close`, `connect`, `print`, etc). There is another module `component01.py` that uses functions from the module `abc.py`. It accesses the module by the statement `import abc`.

Now the framework module `abc.py` does evolve and as a part of it changes its name to `abcd.py` (this is just a simple example, in reality there is a more meaningful reason behind it). This would result in all existing versions of `component01.py` not working anymore. Of course there will be a note to the developer of `component01.py` to adjust, but this takes time. And for the sake of backward compatibility I don't want disable the old module `abc.py` immediately.

This is what I do: I create a new module `abc.py` (since the name is free anew) and put there the following code:

```
import sys
sys.modules['abc'] = sys.modules['abcd']
```

This works well, I still can access the module `abcd.py` with the old name `abc`.

But here comes the problem. I'd like to inform the user that the current implementation of the module `component01.py` uses a deprecated version of the module `abc.py`. After all it is not possible to change its `import abc` statement in the released version. For this I want to add some more lines that throw a warning.

I tried the straight forward solution with `warning.warn()` with `DeprecatedWarning`. It basically works somehow, but the problem is that I can't influence the appearance of the warning the way I'd like. I would prefer to collect the name of the calling module and create a message of my own. However it provided the valuable attribute `stacklevel` that delivered the correct path.

In pursue for another application where `stacklevel` or something comparable can be used I tried other variants of `warning`, I tried `traceback`, I tried `inspect`, manipulation of `sys.modules`, even a sophisticated implementation with `functools`/`wraps`.

But somewhere I always got stuck. The calling module `component01.py` didn't reveal its name/path.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?